# In Aurelia app, How to add some transition between routes?

Tags: aurelia

I`m using Aurelia develop my project, When navigating, i want to add some transition between routes(e.g. fadeIn, fadeOut),but i don't know how to do it ? Thanks.

How to using aurelia-animator-velocity to implement the effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aurelia-animator-css`.
You must put the style `class="au-animate"` on the topmost div in your route file. This **must** be the main div of the html template.

## Sample router HTML

```
<template>    
  <div class="au-animate">  
    <div class="router-body">    
      <div class="router-list">  
      </div>    
    </div>    
  </div>    
</template>
```

## Sample animate CSS

```
@keyframes fadeOutRight {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInRight {
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
.au-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.au-enter-active {
  animation: fadeInRight 0.3s;
}
.au-leave-active {
  animation: fadeOutRight 0.3s;
}
```

## [Aurelia Velocity](http://gooy.github.io/aurelia-animator-velocity/)

To add animations to specific elements:

```
<section anim-enter="fadeIn" anim-leave="fadeOut"></section>
<section anim-enter="{opacity:0};{duration:1000,easing:ease-out}"></section>
```

## Use With JS

To use enter/leave animations on any element the animator has to be invoked *manually*.

To do this inject it into your VM an call the enter/leave methods.

```
import {VelocityAnimator} from "gooy/aurelia-animator-velocity";

    export class MyCustomElement{

      static inject = [Element,VelocityAnimator];
      constructor(element,animator) {
        this.element = element;
        this.animator = animator;
      }

      attached(){
        //run enter animation on the element
        this.animator.enter(this.element);

        //run leave animation on the element
        this.animator.leave(this.element);

        //run an effect on the element
        this.animator.animate(this.element,"callout.bounce");
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer will be `aurelia-animator-css`

here is a basic [tutorial](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/07/17/animating-apps-with-aurelia-part-1/).

Comment: It would be helpful to maybe have a quick snippet/example here instead of just a link.